# Angular 7 - Inserir validação nos input num form dinâmico

Tags: angular, typescript, formulário, validação, angular-7

Fiz um form onde os campos (input) aparecem conforme a categoria a ser criada. A categoria é escolhida quando o usuário clica nela, abrindo uma nova aba pro formulário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No formulário, tem campos com validação. Utilizo o formBuilder para fazer a validação de cada input (Deixei em um campo apenas para dar o exemplo).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu mudar o código que está assim:

```js
this.fiscalForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id_fiscal: [null],
      codigo_empresa: [null],
      nome_empresa: [null],
      cnpj: [null],
      cpf: [null],
      ie: [null],
      im: [null],
      socio_responsavel: [null],
      contador: [null],
      municipio: [null],
      uf: [null],
      login: [null],
      senha: [null, Validators.required],
      site: [null],
      observacao: [null],
    });
```

Para isso:

```js
this.fiscalForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id_fiscal: [null],
      codigo_empresa: [null, Validators.required],
      nome_empresa: [null, Validators.required],
      cnpj: [null, Validators.required],
      cpf: [null, Validators.required],
      ie: [null, Validators.required],
      im: [null, Validators.required],
      socio_responsavel: [null, Validators.required],
      contador: [null, Validators.required],
      municipio: [null, Validators.required],
      uf: [null, Validators.required],
      login: [null, Validators.required],
      senha: [null, Validators.required],
      site: [null, Validators.required],
      observacao: [null, Validators.required],
    });
```

Então o formulário fica inválido, por entender que "existem" campos obrigatórios.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem alguma maneira de remover ou adicionar a validação, conforme os input's que aparecem no formulário?

Código do Componente:

```html
<a (click)="goBack()" class="btn btn-warning btn-md m-3">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span> &lt;&lt; Voltar
</a>
<div class="m-5">
    <h3>{{ pageTitle }}</h3>

</div>

<form class="m-5" [formGroup]="fiscalForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-row" *ngIf="tipo_tabela == 'casn' || tipo_tabela == 'sefaz'">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="codigo_empresa">Código da Empresa</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codigo_empresa" formControlName="codigo_empresa">
      <div class="small" *ngIf="!fiscalForm.controls['codigo_empresa'].valid && fiscalForm.controls['codigo_empresa'].touched"> O Nome do Módulo não pode ficar em branco!</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row" *ngIf="tipo_tabela == 'casn' || tipo_tabela == 'ibge' || tipo_tabela == 'nfgaucha' || tipo_tabela == 'sefaz' || tipo_tabela == 'prefeitura' || tipo_tabela == 'nfse'">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="nome_empresa">Nome da Empresa</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome_empresa" formControlName="nome_empresa">
      <div class="small" *ngIf="!fiscalForm.controls['nome_empresa'].valid && fiscalForm.controls['nome_empresa'].touched"> O Nome do Módulo não pode ficar em branco!</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row" *ngIf="tipo_tabela == 'casn' || tipo_tabela == 'ibge' || tipo_tabela == 'nfgaucha'">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="cnpj">CNPJ</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cnpj" formControlName="cnpj">
      <div class="small" *ngIf="!fiscalForm.controls['cnpj'].valid && fiscalForm.controls['cnpj'].touched"> O Nome do Módulo não pode ficar em branco!</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row" *ngIf="tipo_tabela == 'casn' || tipo_tabela == 'sefaz' || tipo_tabela == 'prefeitura'">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpf" formControlName="cpf">
      <div class="small" *ngIf="!fiscalForm.controls['cpf'].valid && fiscalForm.controls['cpf'].touched"> O Nome do Módulo não pode ficar em branco!</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row" *ngIf="tipo_tabela == 'nfgaucha' || tipo_tabela == 'sefaz'">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="ie">Inscrição Estadual</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ie" formControlName="ie">
      <div class="small" *ngIf="!fiscalForm.controls['ie'].valid && fiscalForm.controls['ie'].touched"> O Nome do Módulo não pode ficar em branco!</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row" *ngIf="tipo_tabela == 'prefeitura'">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="im">Inscrição Municipal</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="im" formControlName="im">
      <div class="small" *ngIf="!fiscalForm.controls['im'].valid && fiscalForm.controls['im'].touched"> O Nome do Módulo não pode ficar em branco!</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row" *ngIf="tipo_tabela == 'sefaz'">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="socio_responsavel">Sócio Responsável</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="socio_responsavel" formControlName="socio_responsavel">
      <div class="small" *ngIf="!fiscalForm.controls['socio_responsavel'].valid && fiscalForm.controls['socio_responsavel'].touched"> O Nome do Módulo não pode ficar em branco!</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row" *ngIf="tipo_tabela == 'aaa'">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="contador">Contador</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contador" formControlName="contador">
      <div class="small" *ngIf="!fiscalForm.controls['contador'].valid && fiscalForm.controls['contador'].touched"> O Nome do Módulo não pode ficar em branco!</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row" *ngIf="tipo_tabela == 'prefeitura' || tipo_tabela == 'nfse'">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="municipio">Município</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="municipio" formControlName="municipio">
      <div class="small" *ngIf="!fiscalForm.controls['municipio'].valid && fiscalForm.controls['municipio'].touched"> O Nome do Módulo não pode ficar em branco!</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row" *ngIf="tipo_tabela == 'sefaz' ">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="uf">UF</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uf" formControlName="uf">
      <div class="small" *ngIf="!fiscalForm.controls['uf'].valid && fiscalForm.controls['uf'].touched"> O Nome do Módulo não pode ficar em branco!</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row" *ngIf="tipo_tabela == 'nfse' ">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="login">Login</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" formControlName="login">
      <div class="small" *ngIf="!fiscalForm.controls['login'].valid && fiscalForm.controls['login'].touched"> O Nome do Módulo não pode ficar em branco!</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row" >
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="senha">Senha</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome_modulo" formControlName="senha">
      <div class="small" *ngIf="!fiscalForm.controls['senha'].valid && fiscalForm.controls['senha'].touched"> O Nome do Módulo não pode ficar em branco!</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row" *ngIf="tipo_tabela == 'nfse' ">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="site">Site</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="site" formControlName="site">
      <div class="small" *ngIf="!fiscalForm.controls['site'].valid && fiscalForm.controls['site'].touched"> O Nome do Módulo não pode ficar em branco!</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row" *ngIf="tipo_tabela == 'prefeitura' ">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="observacao">Observações</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="observacao" formControlName="observacao">
      <div class="small" *ngIf="!fiscalForm.controls['observacao'].valid && fiscalForm.controls['observacao'].touched"> O Nome do Módulo não pode ficar em branco!</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <button [disabled]="!fiscalForm.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg float-right mt-3 mb-4">Salvar</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import { Fiscal } from '../../../interface/fiscal';
import { FiscalService } from '../../../service/fiscal.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fiscal-form',
  templateUrl: './fiscal-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fiscal-form.component.css']
})
export class FiscalFormComponent implements OnInit {

  fiscal: Fiscal;
  id_fiscal: any;
  currentAction: string;
  pageTitle: string;
  fiscalForm: FormGroup;
  tipo_tabela: string;

  constructor(
    private fiscalService: FiscalService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private location: Location
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setCurrentAction();

    this.fiscalForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id_fiscal: [null],
      codigo_empresa: [null, Validators.required],
      nome_empresa: [null, Validators.required],
      cnpj: [null, Validators.required],
      cpf: [null, Validators.required],
      ie: [null, Validators.required],
      im: [null, Validators.required],
      socio_responsavel: [null, Validators.required],
      contador: [null, Validators.required],
      municipio: [null, Validators.required],
      uf: [null, Validators.required],
      login: [null, Validators.required],
      senha: [null, Validators.required],
      site: [null, Validators.required],
      observacao: [null, Validators.required],
    });

    this.loadPage();
  }

  private setCurrentAction() {
    if(this.route.snapshot.url[0].path == 'new') {
      this.currentAction = 'new';
      this.tipo_tabela = this.route.snapshot.url[1].path;

      if(this.route.snapshot.url[1].path == 'municipios'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Criar cadastro (Municípios)';
      } else if(this.route.snapshot.url[1].path == 'estados'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Criar cadastro (Estados)';
      } else if(this.route.snapshot.url[1].path == 'casn'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Criar cadastro (Código Acesso Simples Nacional)';
      } else if(this.route.snapshot.url[1].path == 'ibge'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Criar cadastro (IBGE)';
      } else if(this.route.snapshot.url[1].path == 'nfgaucha'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Criar cadastro (NF Gaúcha)';
      } else if(this.route.snapshot.url[1].path == 'sefaz'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Criar cadastro (SEFAZ)';
      } else if(this.route.snapshot.url[1].path == 'parcelamentos'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Criar cadastro (Parcelamentos)';
      } else if(this.route.snapshot.url[1].path == 'prefeitura'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Criar cadastro (Prefeitura)';
      } else if(this.route.snapshot.url[1].path == 'nfse'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Criar cadastro (NFS-e)';
      } else if(this.route.snapshot.url[1].path == 'grupomacengenharia'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Criar cadastro (Grupo MAC Engenharia)';
      } else {
        this.pageTitle = 'Page Not Found 404';
      }
    } else {
      this.currentAction = 'edit';
      this.id_fiscal = this.route.snapshot.url[0].path;
      this.tipo_tabela = this.route.snapshot.url[2].path;

      if(this.route.snapshot.url[2].path == 'municipios'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Editar cadastro (Municípios)';
      } else if(this.route.snapshot.url[2].path == 'estados'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Editar cadastro (Estados)';
      } else if(this.route.snapshot.url[2].path == 'casn'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Editar cadastro (Código Acesso Simples Nacional)';
      } else if(this.route.snapshot.url[2].path == 'ibge'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Editar cadastro (IBGE)';
      } else if(this.route.snapshot.url[2].path == 'nfgaucha'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Editar cadastro (NF Gaúcha)';
      } else if(this.route.snapshot.url[2].path == 'sefaz'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Editar cadastro (SEFAZ)';
      } else if(this.route.snapshot.url[2].path == 'parcelamentos'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Editar cadastro (Parcelamentos)';
      } else if(this.route.snapshot.url[2].path == 'prefeitura'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Editar cadastro (Prefeitura)';
      } else if(this.route.snapshot.url[2].path == 'nfse'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Editar cadastro (NFS-e)';
      } else if(this.route.snapshot.url[2].path == 'grupomacengenharia'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Editar cadastro (Grupo MAC Engenharia)';
      } else {
        this.pageTitle = 'Page Not Found 404';
      }
    }
  }
  private loadPage() {
    if(this.currentAction == 'edit') {
      this.fiscalService.getId(this.id_fiscal).subscribe(
        (fiscal) => {this.updateForm(fiscal); }
      );
    }
  }
  private updateForm(item) {
    this.fiscalForm.patchValue({
      id_fiscal: item.id_fiscal,
      codigo_empresa: item.codigo_empresa,
      nome_empresa: item.nome_empresa,
      cnpj: item.cnpj,
      cpf: item.cpf,
      ie: item.ie,
      im: item.im,
      socio_responsavel: item.socio_responsavel,
      contador: item.contador,
      municipio: item.municipio,
      uf: item.uf,
      login: item.login,
      senha: item.senha,
      site: item.site,
      observacao: item.observacao,
    });
  }
  goBack() {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro ocorre pois todos os campos são requeridos, ou seja, os campos mesmo que não exibidos vão ser validados, você pode fazer utilizar do setValidators para gerar as validações, por exemplo:

```
...

      if(this.route.snapshot.url[1].path == 'municipios'){
        this.pageTitle = 'Criar cadastro (Municípios)';
        this.addFormValidators(['senha', 'municipio']);
      }

...


  addFormValidators(listaCampos = []) {
      listaCampos.forEach(campo => {
          this.fiscalForm.get(campo).setValidators([Validators.required]);
      });
  }

...
```

Adicionei a função addFormValidators que recebe o nome dos campos que devem ser validados pelo formulário. O correto seria você fazer forms diferentes para cada situação, porém, a refatoração seria enorme. Você pode implementar este código, caso ache mais fácil.

A utilização de apenas um formulário com vários IF's faz o entendimento e a implementação ficar difícil.

Comment: Eu executei o código acima e não resolveu a situação. Acho que o Angular deve estar executando o código sem esperar a função. Vou fazer mais testes e te aviso.

Comment: Funcionou sim, eu que esqueci de tirar o "Validators.required" do onInit. Valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: para criar está funcionando, mas para editar as validações não são inseridas nos campos, vou abrir uma outra pergunta com o erro que aparece

Comment: Consegui arrumar, no onInit, eu insiro a validação antes de criar o formBuilder, por isso deu o erro, só troquei as funções de lugar (formbuilder antes de todos) e funcionou direitinho! Mais uma vez, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado @EdwardRamos